# Correct way of doing bulk operations through scheduled taks?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, scheduled-tasks, bulk

In my application, I have set of scheduled tasks which process all users' data and perform various tasks like earning, tax calculations, generate statements for all users. Since these processes need to run for each user, they take a lot of time(many hours) because of large number of users. Data processing for one user is completely independent from another user's, so they can be run in parallel. What are my options here? What are the best practices for doing such large/bulk operations. 
We are using J2SE platform with spring, jpa and hibernate.

Comment: Without knowing the exact nature of your domain it's hard to tell, but the pointers to Spring Batch are definitely worthwhile. In any case I'd strive to keep all the processing data in memory - only go to the database when you're done processing. You may want to look into http://lmax-exchange.github.com/disruptor/ for help, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be doing the same via batch.

Since you have mentioned that you were doing with Spring you can consider using [Spring Batch](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/).

> Spring Batch provides reusable functions that are essential in
>   processing large volumes of records, including logging/tracing,
>   transaction management, job processing statistics, job restart, skip,
>   and resource management. It also provides more advanced technical
>   services and features that will enable extremely high-volume and high
>   performance batch jobs through optimization and partitioning
>   techniques.

Check out the [Reference manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/index.html) on how to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the spring documentation for scheduled tasks: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html

I find the easiest way to do scheduled tasks is to use @Scheduled annotation, and you can use cron style timing.  For each of your users, you could perform your task in a different Thread for each:

```
@Scheduled(cron="*/5 * * * * MON-FRI")
public void doSomething() {
    List<User> users = getUsers();
    for(User user: users) {
        MyTask task = new MyTask(user);
        Thread t = new Thread(task);
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Make sure MyTask is a Runnable.

If you have mountains of data and users, you could look at Spring Batch: http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/